# How to use correct Jquery animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation

I have 2 animations curtain . The first animation work should be loaded as soon as the page , the second should work when you roll over the unit with a shutter and thus turn off the first animation . But I have run two animations at the same time until you will not deduce the cursor over the unit and will not return it back . What should I do?

```
function animationCurtain() {
    $('.black_white').stop(true, true).animate({
        width: "-=-100px"
    }, 1200, function () {
        $('.black_white').stop(true, true).animate({
            width: "-=100px"
        }, 1200, animationCurtain);
    });

}
animationCurtain();

$(".before_after_slider").hover(function () {
    $('.before_after_slider').mousemove(function (e) {
        var offX = (e.offsetX || e.clientX - $black_white.offset().left);
        $black_white.width(offX);
    });

    $('.before_after_slider').mouseleave(function (e) {
        $black_white.stop().animate({
            width: init_split
        }, 100)
    });
});
```

Comment: Please put your code here as well using code tags

Comment: For better understanding, Please provide a **working demo** (*code snippet,jsfiddle ...*)